# Why does not htaccess work on localhost?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I took these steps:

1. Enabled LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf
2. Created .htaccess file with "deny from all" and a blank line
3. Restarted Apache 2.4

However, when I go to the folder containing this .htaccess (localhost/upload/), I see other files in it:

> Index of /upload/
>
> Parent Directory
>
> ... list goes on

What is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

This is how .htaccess looks like now:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

And this line was uncommented in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

All the rest was left unchanged and default.

Comment: You forgot to tell your host to interpret `.htaccess` style files. Take a look at apaches `AllowOverride` command.

Comment: Also you want to think about if you really need to use `.htaccess` style files. Why don't you place your commands in the host configuration instead? `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone and unreliable, they are hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down. They are only offered for those users who do _not_ have control over the host configuration (as it often is the case with cheap web space providers).

Comment: I tried dozens different commands in .htaccess, but none of them works

Comment: Did you even bother to _read_ what I wrote in my first comment?

Comment: Not only I read, I even tried to use it, but in vain. Probably, you mean something really subtle, that should be followed along dot by dot. So, if you could elaborate on this, that would be helpful.

Comment: So, do you know what configuration to take and how .htaccess should look like to prevent a user from listing some folder in browser?

Comment: The apache documentation lists the `AllowOverride` command: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride You have to use it inside your host configuration to enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files first. Without that those files are simply ignored. You probably want to start with a `AllowOverride All` inside your main `<Directory ...>` definition.

Comment: Here is a well written `HowTo` explaining many interesting details of those files: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html It is well worth reading...

Comment: `<Directory /> AllowOverride All Deny from all</Directory>` does not work. Many other combinations also do not work. So if you know the exact vodoo spell, please, bring it to the light. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your host configuration and the current version of your `.htaccess` style file. Also the last lines of your apaches error log file after you restarted the deamon. Then we have some more specific details. Please do _not_ add those things in comments, use the `edit` button provided below your question. thanks.

Comment: I did it. Please, have a look.

Comment: The `<Directory ...>` command belongs into the host configuration, as written. Think of it this way: if you want to enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files, then this won't work if you place the command inside such a file, will it? Don't worry, we all learn and you certainly will succeed! The host configuration is that part of your apache http server configuration where the `host` is defined. Either the default host (serving all requests to that server) or a virtual host. Look for a `<Directory ...>` command in that configuration and extend it with `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Let me just ask you one tiny question?) Do you know how .htaccess should look like to achive that simple task? I know, there are brilliant tutorials, wonderful CS books, gorgeos lectures and so on...

Comment: Could you drop those magic commands that I should put to .htaccess to make it work?)

Comment: I posted a full answer below to prevent further confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed above in the comments you first need to enable the interpretation of those `.htaccess` style files. Before you do that they are simply ignored.

For that apache offers the command `AllowOverride`. Place it inside the `<Directory ...>` section of your host configuration which defines the rules you want to have applied to the location where you want those files to be interpreted. So something like:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/documents"
    <Directory "/var/www/documents">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Your `.htaccess` style file need that content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

That should work, as far as I can say without trying it now myself. 
Anyhow you really should start monitoring your http servers error log file (also as already written above in the comments). It allows you to understand what is wrong with your setup, for example in case of syntax errors. The typical location of that log file is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but it might vary, depending on your setup again. Look for the `CustomLog` command in your apache configuration which defines the location of that log file.

---

I would like to repeat my second comment here however:

You want to think about if you really need to use `.htaccess` style files. Why don't you place your commands in the host configuration instead? `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone and unreliable, they are hard to debug and really slow the server down. They are only offered for those users who do not have control over the host configuration (as it often is the case with cheap web space providers).

You can achieve the same result without any `.htaccess` style file by adding another `<Directory ...>` command to your host definition:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/documents"

    <Directory "/var/www/documents">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/documents/protected/area">
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```